# Check for ARC in precompile

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have an iOS refactoring library that I want to work with and without the ARC compilation option.  Is there a way to detect during compilation, like with an `#ifdef`, if ARC is available?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  ...
#endif
```

Even if you're using the latest version of LLVM, this will only evaluate to true if you're compiling with the `-fobjc-arc` option.

Comment: It seems to be working!  I'll just wrap my retain/release stuff in that.

Comment: +1, also thanks to your answer I found `__has_feature(objc_arc_weak)`