# How to know if my Xcode iPhone project is using ARC?

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I want to know if my Xcode iPhone project is using ARC, and I can't remember if I ticked that box when creating the project.

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Select your project, then **Build Settings**. Look for **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** in the **Apple LLVM Compiler - Language** section. Make sure you select the target; while you can set this in the project, the target can override it.

(You can also use the search bar in Build Settings for `OBJC_ARC`.)

Keep in mind, too, that you can turn ARC on or off on a per file basis in build phases.

Or, just try something like this in code:

```
[[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease]
```

If you get an error:

```
ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
```

Then you're using ARC.

You can also require ARC from a source code file by checking for it:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This file must be built with ARC.
// You can turn on ARC for only this file by adding -fobjc-arc to the build phase.
#endif
```

Comment: My project is using ARC but still, I don't get an error when release appears in the code. I have no flag skipping ARC either. Any idea why?

Comment: My guess is that ARC really isn't in use for some reason. Try using the #if described here, but put an #error inside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708267/check-for-arc-in-precompile

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback. I couldn't figure out where the problem was coming from exactly, but it seems it was related to some cocoapods bug. Upgrading cocoapods and relauching the pods (and thus the .xcworkspace file) solved my problem.

Answer (score 21):

Just search for **Automatic** in your target's build settings:

[image]